# Display row and column number on status bar of notepad

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, notepad

Can anyone please help me regarding how can the row number and column number be displayed on status bar in a notepad program in C#?

Answer (score 1):

click on view then click on status bar it will be in the bottom right of the screen

Comment: I'm writing my own notepad and asking for the code.

Comment: Meaning want to get line and column information for textArea ..!!

Comment: oh sorry missread your question there

Comment: anyway could always look at how notepad++ does things might give you some ideas later on? heres the source code location http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/files/notepad%2B%2B%20releases%20source/